# {this.props.children} and route params of Parent?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Let's say my routes look like this

```
<Router history={browserHistory>
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
   <Route path="project/:id" component={Project}>
     <Route path="info" component={projectInfo} />
     <Route path="details" component={projectDetails />
   </Route>
  </Route>
</Router>
```

I want to fetch from the database the project with the id, that's obvious. But if in the Project component I write {this.props.children} how do I pass on the id to the projectInfo component so I can do have the information there. Or would I not do it like this?

I would use the  in Project to navigate to the child components but how do I get the id to them!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could access the id with this.props.params.id.

The route /project/1 would return an id of 1.

Comment: Is that because the projectInfo Component is just reading off the entire url, so it has access to the :id? So, it isn't the path in the component's <Route>, but the url that the component has access too..

Comment: I am not fully sure I understand what you're getting at, but parameters are passed through the URL, yes. The :parameter you set in your route will share a name with what you pull in this.props.params.

Comment: I figured it out, I pass the props down and its available in projectInfo. Problem now is with absolute vs relative linking. Thanks